# Cannot pass image to ML5 with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying out ML5 for image classification

I am unable to pass the image into the ML5 predict function. The error says No input image provided.

I am using React Dropzone to drag and drop the image which i then pass to ML5 library

Anyone has experience integrating React with ML5? How should I pass img to the classifier to classify the image?

Thanks for your response

```
class ml5Page extends Component {
  onDrop = async acceptedFiles => {
    try {
      const img = URL.createObjectURL(acceptedFiles[0]);
      const classifier = await ml5.imageClassifier("MobileNet");
      const results = await classifier.predict(img);
      console.log("@results ", results);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Content style={ContentStyle}>
        <div>
          <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop}>
            {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
              <section>
                <div {...getRootProps()}>
                  <input {...getInputProps()} />
                  <p>Drop Pic Here</p>
                </div>
              </section>
            )}
          </Dropzone>
        </div>
      </Content>
    );
  }
}

export default ml5Page;
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to work. It seems must retrieve img from the DOM using React.createRef() [Working Codes for implementing React with ML5](https://github.com/myhendry/lab/blob/master/web-js/src/modules/ml5/image/ml5ImagePage.jsx)